# Single SMS won't delete from Messaging app

Tags: sms, delete

I have a phone (HUAWEI Y6 2018) that recently received a text message claiming to be from a postal company (AusPost). However, the subject for the message simply says '(No subject)', and when I try to open the message, it just won't open. With this in mind, I tried to delete the text, only to see it not delete and stay on the page. I've tried a few things to delete this text, such as:

- Clearing both data and the cache for the messaging app
- Trying to locate the folder where the messages are stored (I can't seem to find it)
- Downloading apps such as [Handcent](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.handcent.app.nextsms) and [Backup & Restore](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.riteshsahu.SMSBackupRestore) to use their delete SMS features
- Installing the latest system update and trying again
- Adding a contact called "AusPost" and deleting the message

All to no prevail... the SMS just seems to be stuck in the inbox.
So what do I do now? I don't want to root my phone and I want this message gone.

Comment: is it really inbox or do you mean notification bar

Comment: @alecxs it is most definitely in the inbox

Comment: "...the subject for the message simply says '(No subject)'" - This sounds more like an MMS, as opposed to an SMS?

Comment: Well, it could be an MMS, but how would I be able to tell?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What turned out being the solution was to just factory reset the phone and ensure that everything was backed up - - thankfully, there wasn't too much that was deleted.

Answer (score 0):

You can install MyPhoneExplorer for PC and remote administrate your messages

Comment: Will definitely look into this in the morning.

Comment: Tried it out just now but the SMS didn't show up on the messages page, despite the fact it is still in the inbox